# Unable to capture http log for some part of page with Charlesproxy or Fiddler?

Tags: json, httprequest, web-crawler, fiddler, charles-proxy

I am trying to check the data loading into search listing in this page link below :

http://www.tigerdirectwireless.com/ecommerce/phones/?r=tigerdirect&filterbycarrier=68

We could not find the product details(name, price etc.) in page source. I have inspected in both [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) , but not able to view a log of any http request or response for this data.

Even after saving a complete webpage will not not download the listing products details, nor [HTTrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/) we help us identifying this.

We actually want the know the link from where this response data in generating in text/markup format.

Thanks Guys.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is sent back in JSON and the page is built up dynamically using JavaScript. For instance `http://www.tigerdirectwireless.com/eCommerce/Service/CoreServicesProxy.asmx/GetPartnerPhoneList` is the JSON response that contains the list of phones and details, while `http://www.tigerdirectwireless.com/eCommerce/Service/CoreServicesProxy.asmx/GetPartnerPricedPhoneList` contains the phones and prices.

Comment: Nice explanation there EricLaw, but why cannot I see any response in Fiddler OR Charles regarding the productname or price. How could anything is displayed without catching in HTTP response. There should be a dynamic link generated, which we could directly request in browser? Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Both the product name and the price are contained in the JSON HTTP responses mentioned.

Comment: could you help me finding a direct link for the data on this page : http://www.tigerdirectwireless.com/ecommerce/phones/?filterbybrand=13&referringdomain=tigerdirect

Comment: The URLs are exactly the ones I already provided, to wit: `http://www.tigerdirectwireless.com/eCommerce/Service/CoreServicesProxy.asmx/GetPartnerPricedPhoneList` and 
`http://www.tigerdirectwireless.com/eCommerce/Service/CoreServicesProxy.asmx/GetPartnerPhoneList`

Comment: EricLaw, I cannot see the data on the link, what i need is: For this link : http://shop.nordstrom.com/c/mens-bags-cases?dept=8000001&origin=topnav#category=b60140094&type=category&currency=INR&page=3&color=&price=&brand=&instoreavailability=false&lastfilter=&sizeFinderId=0&resultsmode=&segmentId=0    - data is coming from this link(i.e all the products on page:3) : http://shop.nordstrom.com/FashionSearch.axd?category=b60140094&contextualsortcategoryid=0&currency=INR&instoreavailability=false&page=3&pagesize=100&partial=1&type=category&   --similarly i require the data link for tigerdirect.

Comment: I have no idea what "see the data on the link" means. These JSON responses contain all of the data that identifies the products and their prices, just like the Nordstrom example you show. For the TigerDirect pages, you cannot simply request the JSON directly using a `GET`, you must do so exactly as the original TigerDirect HTML page does.

Comment: Thanks EricLaw. This should help.